# nodejs: error-handling for http requests when passed as writeable streams

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm  trying to write a function that streams to either a file or an http put request.  I'd like to be able to write something like:

```
stream_data_to(dest, cb)
```

Where cb(err) is called when the data is successfully saved or when an error occurs.

I'm assuming the way to do this is for dest to be a writeable stream, and do something like:

```
stream_data_to(dest, cb) {
    my_source.pipe(dest);
    dest.on('finish', cb);
    dest.on('error', function(err) { cb(err); }
}
```

This seems fine for files, but for http requests, I think 'finished' is called when the data is transmitted to the remote server, but before the server sends a response.  I'd like stream_data_to not to call back until the remote server confirms the put was successful.

Is there a way of doing that while keeping stream_data_to agnostic to what kind of destination it is?  This seems like something that should be easy to do in node, so I feel like I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: Your solution is perfect, it perfectly tells you than you sent the request.  However, HTTP isn't a stream, it's two streams, one request stream and then one response stream (you can pretend it's a duplex stream, like the request module does).  That being said you should be able to write a function that does what you want it too, it'll just need to be http aware.

Comment: Idea: Use instanceOf to check the type of dest: "http.request() returns an instance of the http.ClientRequest class"